# Reactjs siblings class toggle

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, events, components

*I dont want to use two classes*

How can i make the sibling box appear green when button is hover ?

Currently all the boxes are hovered green.

Below is the code with the snippet.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```js
class Lol extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      green : false
    };
  }
  render = () =>{
    let green = (this.state.green) ? 'green' : '';
    let outs = [];
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      outs.push( 
        <div>
          <button onMouseOver={() => {
              this.setState({green : true});
           }}
           onMouseLeave={() => {
              this.setState({green : false});
           }}  
          >
           Turn box green 
         </button>
         <div className={'box '+green}>
         </div>
       </div>
       );
    }
    return (
       <div>
        {outs}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Lol />,document.getElementById("a"));
```

```css
.box{
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying the next sibling like the css `+` selector?

Comment: Alright, I deleted my answer since you explicitly said you don't want multiple classes. May I ask why you have that constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index of the hovered item in state, as well as whether or not something is hovered. Then compare the stored index with the current iteration index:

```js
class Lol extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      greenIndex: null
    };
  }
  render = () =>{
    
    let outs = [];
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
      const { greenIndex } = this.state;
      const greenClass = (greenIndex === i) ? 'green' : '';

      outs.push( 
        <div>
          <button onMouseOver={() => {
              this.setState({ greenIndex: i });
           }}
           onMouseLeave={() => {
              this.setState({ greenIndex: null });
           }}  
          >
           Turn box green 
         </button>
         <div className={'box '+greenClass}>
         </div>
       </div>
       );
    }
    return (
       <div>
        {outs}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Lol />,document.getElementById("a"));
```

```css
.box{
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="a">
  </div>
```

Comment: This solution cuts to the chase much more quickly than mine does, and it also adds unique element ids, which react likes.

The only thing going for my solution is that there really is no reason that the global component needs to keep track of green in its state.

Comment: This works, although ideally each button would be broken down into their own component in charge of their own state.

Comment: @jered yes I agree, however I was trying to respect OP's request: `I dont want to use two classes` (I interpreted that to mean React class, not CSS class)